# Function with code as parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I have lots of functions, But I do need to run them inside another function.

I know I can do something like this

```
public void Method1()
{
bla bla
}


public void Method2()
{
bla bla
}

public void Wrapper(Action<string> myMethod)
        {
        method{
            myMethod()
              }
            bla bla
         }
```

And then call them using something like this:

```
wrapper(Method1());
```

The issue is tha sometimes I need to run Method1, and Method2, at the same time. They are a lot. 
Sometimes One, sometimes several at the same time.

So I am thinking that would be great to do something like this:

```
Wrapper({bla bla bla; method(); bla bla; }
{
method{
bla bla bla;
 method();
 bla bla;

        }
}
```

Run a code block inside a method, and the parameter of the method is the code block.
Do you think is it possible or would you recommend another approach?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx may help.

Comment: If you want to pass a code block to a function for execution, what you want is a lambda. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having

```
public static void Wrapper(Action<string> myMethod)
{
    //...
}
```

you may specify `myMethod` using [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Wrapper((s) =>
    {
        //actually whatever here
        int a;
        bool b;
        //..
        Method1();
        Method2();
        //and so on
    });
}
```

That is you don't need to explicitly define a method with the desired signature (here matching `Action<string>`), but you may write inline lambda expression, doing whataever you need.

From MSDN:

> By using lambda expressions, you can write local functions that can be
>   passed as arguments or returned as the value of function calls.

Comment: What s means in  Wrapper((s) =>

Comment: @RicardoPolo this is equivalent to `Action<string> a = (s) => { };` and then `Wrapper(a);`

Comment: where `(s) => { }` is a lambda expression

Comment: read about it [MSDN Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you already have some method that accepts an Action parameter, you can just use an anonymous method to group a bunch of methods together for sequential execution.

```
//what you have
public void RunThatAction(Action TheAction)
{
  TheAction()
}

//how you call it
Action doManyThings = () =>
{
  DoThatThing();
  DoThatOtherThing();
}
RunThatAction(doManyThings);
```

---

If calling methods sequentially is something you do often, consider making a function that accepts as many Actions as you have...

```
public void RunTheseActions(params Action[] TheActions)
{
  foreach(Action theAction in TheActions)
  {
    theAction();
  }
}

//called by
RunTheseActions(ThisAction, ThatAction, TheOtherAction);
```

---

You said "at the same time" twice, which makes me think of parallelism.  If you want to run many methods simultaneously, you can use Tasks to do that.

```
public void RunTheseActionsInParallel(params Action[] TheActions)
{
  List<Task> myTasks = new List<Task>(TheActions.Count);
  foreach(Action theAction in TheActions)
  {
    Task newTask = Task.Run(theAction);
    myTasks.Add(newTask);
  }
  foreach(Task theTask in myTasks)
  {
    theTask.Wait();
  }
}
```